# How to keep all possible combinations in collapse by multiple variables in stata?

Tags: stata

When I `collapse` a dataset by multiple variables, by default, Stata keeps only the combinations for which there are observations and so statistics can be calculated. What can I do to keep all combinations, with a missing result for the statistics that can't be computed? In an example:

```
sysuse nlsw88, clear

collapse (mean) grade, by(race occupation)

table occupation race

--------------------------------------------
                       |        race        
            occupation | white  black  other
-----------------------+--------------------
Professional/technical |     1      1      1
        Managers/admin |     1      1      1
                 Sales |     1      1      1
    Clerical/unskilled |     1      1       
             Craftsmen |     1      1       
            Operatives |     1      1      1
             Transport |     1      1       
              Laborers |     1      1      1
               Farmers |     1              
         Farm laborers |     1      1       
               Service |     1      1       
     Household workers |     1              
                 Other |     1      1       
--------------------------------------------

. list if race == 2 & occupation == 9
```

You can see that there are no observations for black farmers. What I would like to have is:

```
. list if race == 2 & occupation == 9

     +--------------------------+
     |  race   occupa~n   grade |
     |--------------------------|
 32. | black    Farmers       . |
     +--------------------------+
```

Comment: @ander2ed has a fine answer. Accept it to give yourself and ander2ed deserved reputation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `fillin` for this:

```
sysuse nlsw88, clear
collapse (mean) grade, by(race occupation)

fillin occupation race
table occupation race


                       |        race        
            occupation | white  black  other
-----------------------+--------------------
Professional/technical |     1      1      1
        Managers/admin |     1      1      1
                 Sales |     1      1      1
    Clerical/unskilled |     1      1      1
             Craftsmen |     1      1      1
            Operatives |     1      1      1
             Transport |     1      1      1
              Laborers |     1      1      1
               Farmers |     1      1      1
         Farm laborers |     1      1      1
               Service |     1      1      1
     Household workers |     1      1      1
                 Other |     1      1      1
--------------------------------------------

list if race == 2 & occupation == 9

     +------------------------------------+
     |  race   occupa~n   grade   _fillin |
     |------------------------------------|
 26. | black    Farmers       .         1 |
     +------------------------------------+
```

According to the help file for `fillin`:

> **fillin** adds observations with missing data so that all interactions of *varlist* exist